# Black Hole Heat Capacity

Tags: general-relativity, thermodynamics, black-holes

Why is the specific heat capacity of a black hole given by $C=\frac{\partial M}{\partial T}$? Heat capacity should be ratio of heat change to temperature change so, denoting heat by $Q$, we have $C=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T}$. Then if I assume my black hole isn't rotating or charged, the first law tells me $dM=\frac{\kappa}{8 \pi} dA$. Somehow I need to relate heat to area in order to get a mass in the formula? I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track here....

Comment: Maybe $E=Mc^2$? (where we usually take $c=1$...)

Answer (score 1):

For a black hole, the temperature at infinity, in natural units
$$ T = \frac{1}{8\pi M}$$
and the entropy
$$S = \pi R^2 = 4\pi M^2$$

The change in heat content 
$$dQ = T\ dS = 8\pi M T\ dM =  dM$$

So
$$C_v =\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial T}$$

Comment: Thanks for this. However, your answer seems to rely on $T=\frac{1}{8 \pi M}$ which is true for e.g. Schwarzschild black holes but I have seen this formula applied elsewhere e.g. black holes in AdS. Is this still OK?

Comment: @You said the black hole wasn't rotating or charged.

Comment: Yes let us assume it isn't rotating. But will we still have the same relationship between temperature and mass even if the space isn't asymptotically flat?